# Why does Master Ip want to sew a button onto a paper?

Tags: plot-explanation, ip-man-3

In the martial arts movie Ip Man 3 from 2015 Master Ip asks his wife to sew a button onto a paper and she does it. So why does he want to sew a button onto that paper?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He left a note asking the wife to help him sew the button on (back onto the coat).
But the wife took it literally as a joke and sewed it onto the paper.

Comment: I waited for this answer for almost an year.